# Repetitions on the same combination of factors in mixed ANOVA and its power analysis

Tags: r, statistics, anova, mixed-models, sample-size

I am trying to decide the appropriate model and perform power analysis. Suppose a data contains 2 groups (A,B) and 28 participants from each group. All of those participants are measured 15 times on each of 8 different conditions (c1,c2,....,c8), so each participant get 8*15=120 continuous measurements in total. I understand the sample size should depends on the power analysis results so I am just giving example numbers referring to related studies in the same field.

The major question to be answered by the model is whether there is significant difference difference of c1 and c2 for group B, and difference of A and B in c1 (and some other similar comparisons). So the major goal is to test particular simple main effect or maybe called planned contrast.

My question is related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46321/how-to-deal-with-repeated-measurements-in-the-same-condition-of-a-factorial-expe but more about power analysis. I believe I can use either mixed ANOVA (groups as fixed between effect, conditions as fixed within effect, and participants as random effect) or mixed modeling. However, I don't usually observe *repetitions* (each participants has 15 measurements on each condition) in a repeated measures ANOVA or mixed ANOVA. Therefore my concerns are as below.

1. If I could do mixed ANOVA, I plan to use `Superpower` package for power analysis. But the 'n' in `ANOVA_design` seems only refer to number of participants and there seems no way to consider number of repetitions. How to specify repetition number in `Superpower`?
   Similarly, G*Power software only allows input of 'Number of groups' (between factor) and 'Number of measurements' (within factor). Does this mean that the *repetition* doesn't affect the power? But my understanding is that it would at least affects the df of denominator and so the power.
2. For either mixed model or mixed ANOVA, should the power analysis be done on the planned contrast at all?
3. If yes to question 2, for a mixed effect model, how can `simr` beused for the power calculation for the planned contrast and simple main effect?

Thanks in advance and your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be lacking a description of an analysis proposal. Without a null and an parametrized set of alternate hypotheses, I don’t see how a power analysis can be conducted.

Comment: Thanks. Some more information is added for the hypothesis test. I am also aware that some parameters about the model need to be provided for a power calculation.

Comment: Seems an extremely small sample size for any test of interactions, even if this were not a repeated measures proposal. Sample size is not increased by the number of measurements. Your also proposing multiple tests and haven't described any sort of adjustment for the multiple comparisons problem. It appears to me that you _should_ have conducted this effort _prior_ to gathering any data. Then you would have a better notion of the number necessary for the chosen research question. This all appears to be much more in line with the sorts of question(s) posed on https://stats.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM I've edited my question to further clarify it. The major goal is to test the planned contrast. Also, this is a plan for analysis and I understand the sample may be small. So could you share information how to use Superpower or G*Power for the sample size determination in my questions (particularly how to include repetition in the functions)? Also for 'Seems an extremely small sample size for any test of interactions, even if this were not a repeated measures proposal.', I thought with repeated measure the power tended to be higher than without repeated measures.

Comment: You have 28 subjects and want to estimate 8 different “conditions”. Each condition has 15 continuous measurements done under some unspecified situations, perhaps over some time variable or different days? Is there any prior work that lets you estimate the  variances of the outcomes for a single subject under individual conditions? I suppose there might be some improvements if the variances were small enough. But you have not described any prior work that would provide support for a power analysis. Also no plans for dealing with multiple comparisons issues.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM, the 15 measurements is just repetitions so there is no additional time or condition factors (the only factors are 2 groups, 8 conditions, and the random effect of participants). The major question is not about the multiple comparisons because I only care about certain contrasts or several so-called simple main effects. Also, I've checked the arguments of 'Superpower::Anova_design'. I have data to estimate the `mu` vector in the function. I am just curious what value should be input into `n` in my case.

Comment: Also, do you mean `sd` in the function should be standard deviation of the outcomes for a single subject under individual conditions? Could you also clarify what the argument `r` is as there is very few source for what it is and how to estimate it? Thanks.

Comment: This dialog should stand as evidence that neither of us is in a position to start coding. You need a statistical consultation.